# Reading files and undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, io, ifstream

Lately I've stumbled across a post: [How to read an entire file into memory in C++](http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/how-to-read-an-entire-file-into-memory-in-cpp/) where different techniques for reading files are described. Each approach is commented about its efficiency or risks related to *undefined behaviour*.
Among the list the following example is presented:

```
// Bad code; undefined behaviour
in.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
```

Which basically in this or a similar form is often used to actually read the file size.
The reasoning presented in the post, in short, is that in `C standard (N1570) §7.21.3` it is stated that:

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with
>   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream
>   (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with
>   state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial
>   shift state.

Which is `footnote 268` for:

> A file need not begin nor end in the initial shift state

To confirm the above for C++11 there is an additional reference to `C++ standard draft (N3242) 27.9.1.1` which states:

> The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an
>   object of class basic_filebuf are the same as for reading and writing
>   with the Standard C library FILEs.

Where `basic_filebuf` according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) is a part of implementation for `basic_ifstream` (internal buffer). Which points that `ifstream` implementation should be also burdened with the denoted behaviour.

From what I've understood from the description and from what I've managed to dig, this issue is mostly related to wide-oriented streams which may not end in the `initial shift state`.

Seems to me this cannot be a typical case due to the popular usage for file size calculation. Still the topic is not quite clear for me. Hence, the following **questions**:

- What is actually the `initial state shift`? I assume it cannot be related to data clusters. More to the multibyte char encoding but this way wouldn't the problem be only limited to non-binary streams?
- When actually do we deal with `wide-` and `narrow-oriented`streams? I am aware that: `"A newly opened stream has no orientation."` and the orientation is decided on the first I/O call to the stream. But in practice are there, let's say, any defaults dependent on stream type, system, locale or something else?
- If not already answered or denoted, what is a practical example on when such undefined behaviour could occur? In the sense that one could reproduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["shift state"](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Shift-State.html) - limited indeed to multibyte text streams (and EOL treatment `\r\n` vs `\n`) and **this** problem will be limited to text streams indeed.

But that is not the *only* problem. From the article you cited, with my emphasis:

> Some platforms store files as fixed-size records. If the file is shorter than the record size, the rest of the block is padded. When you seek to the “end”, *for efficiency’s sake it just jumps you right to the end of the last block… possibly long **after the actual end of the data**, after a bunch of padding.*

`fseek(p_file, 0, SEEK_END)` followed by `ftell(...)` affords a valid answer only as long as `EOF` flag is not raised. 
Read "The solution (really large files)" section of the cited as it provides the details, particularly:
 step 4. "Restore the stream to the start position with `seekg()`. *This will also clear the EOF flag.*"

Question in comments:

> do you have the knowledge which platforms particularly?

Google landed me on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Record-oriented_file_systems) of record-oriented file systems - mainly mainframes, some of which are still used.

Another area which may be a "record files" area: "the cloud". You never know when somebody is going to (re)incarnate [Distributed Data Management Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Data_Management_Architecture) and hit problems solvable by [record-oriented files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Data_Management_Architecture#Record-oriented_files).
For all I know (which is next to nothing), NFS *may* be already doing it: the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3530) speaks about "record lock".

One of top of the other, I'd be paying attention to the standard and treat this matter with respect when writing "truly standard, cross-platform compatible software" in C/C++.

Comment: You are correct I saw that too. It would make the acquired size incorrect. Still the conclusion was that: `You can get the number of characters with ftell() in binary mode… but you can’t seek to the end of the file with fseek(p_file, 0, SEEK_END).` Additionally the `Some platforms store files as fixed-size records` statement - do you have the knowledge which platforms particularly? The solution presented by author using `gcount` looks valid. However, I'm more interested on where the `seek-to-end-to-get-size` approach may fail in practice.

Comment: @Dusteh some extra info posted in the answer. This being said, I really don't know how to repro a "record-oriented file access" on the usual OS-es available to me.